# Rally specifying minHeight on cardboard

Tags: rally

I am creating a cardboard and specifying the min and max heights for the cards on that board.  When I specify a range

```
cardConfig: {xtype: 'rallycard', minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 150}, // all cards on the board have height 100
```

all of the cards take on the minHeight.  If I just specify a minHeight (and no maxHeight) the same thing happens.

If I just specify a maxHeight, then I get the expected functionality - the cards take on heights up to the maximum specified.

Why does specifying a minHeight effectively just specify a height for all cards, and how can I specify a range?

Comment: if I specify a height and a minHeight, the larger one overrides the other!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the same inconsistency between the effect of minHeight and the effect on maxHeight on a card's height, and filed a defect. As far as your comment  about height and minHeight, I think this is a reasonable outcome given the ambiguity that exists if both are specified.